# Google App Engine: Using cron to expire (or 'unpublish') entities

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, app-engine-ndb

I would like to mimic the 'published/unpublished' functionality of common CMS platforms like Wordpress or Drupal.

So I have this Job(ndb.Model):

```
class Job(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    published = ndb.StringProperty(default = "on")
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    expire = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
```

The NewJob handler looks like this:

```
class NewJob(JobHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.render('new-job.html')

    def post(self):
        title = self.request.get('title')
        published = "on"

        expire = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days = 30)

        if title:
            j = Job(
                title = title, 
                published = published,
                expire = expire,
                created = created)
            j.put()
            self.redirect('/job/%s' % str(j.key.id()))
        else:
            self.redirect('/login')
```

And the saved entity looks something like this:

```
Job(key=Key('Job', 5910974510923776), created=datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 17, 19, 0, 52, 12379), expire=datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 17, 19, 1, 52, 12174), published=u'on', title=u'Sous Chef')
```

What I am aiming to do is to set all `Job` entities to 'publish == "off"' when the their `expire` time is today (now)

So I've set up a task in the cron.yaml

```
cron: 
- description: expire job entities after 30 days
  url: /cron/job-expire
  schedule: every day 00:00
```

...and the `/cron/job-expire` url is handled by:

```
class CronJobExpire(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        jobs = Job.query(Job.published == "on").fetch()
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        for job in jobs:
            if job.expire < now or job.expire == now:
                job.published = "off"
```

The aim of the `CronJobExpire` handler above is to:

Check through the list of Job entities which are currently `published == "on"`, then
check if their `expire` dates are '`now`' or '`< now`', and if this is True, set `published == "off"`.

This doesn't work. I am following the documentation. Any help would be appreciated - thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the jobs that you changed:

```
class CronJobExpire(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        jobs = Job.query(Job.published == "on").fetch()
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        for job in jobs:
            if job.expire <= now:
                job.published = "off"    
                job.put()
```

Also, I suggest fetching only the expired jobs:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()    
jobs = Job.query(Job.published == "on", Job.expire <= now).fetch()
for job in jobs:
    job.published = "off"
    job.put()
```

Or, to reduce API calls and therefore improve speed:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()    
jobs = Job.query(Job.published == "on", Job.expire <= now).fetch()
for job in jobs:
    job.published = "off"
ndb.put_multi(jobs)
```

Lastly, consider making Job.published a boolean:

```
published = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)
```

Comment: Silly me. Thank you for the additional suggestions.